# Recording square video using webcam winrt?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I'm using the MediaCapture api in WinRT and recording with the following code:

```
var enc = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingQuality.Vga);
enc.Video.Width = 480;
enc.Video.Height = 480;
enc.Video.Bitrate = 1000000;
await vidCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(enc, videoStream);
```

But the problem is I'm trying to record a video 480x480.  The end result is great except it is widescreen (black bars on top and bottom).  Is there a way to crop or change the aspect ratio.  Or at least make the background white (bars).

Comment: Did you figure it out?